# Error: Found argument '-m' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context while invoking FirefoxDriver and Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I had some issues with the Chrome driver so I want to make a switch to the Firefox driver. I want to create a headless browser with im getting an error that I cannot resolve.

*1523632397476   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.20.0
1523632397483   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:60008*

*error: Found argument '-m' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context*

I create my driver like this:

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\xxx\geckodriver.exe";
options.AddArgument("--headless");
c._driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I did something similar with the ChromeDriver without any issue.

All the versions are up to date.

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong or show me how to create a FireFox driver in headless mode. That would be awesome!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the *API Docs* of [**FirefoxOptions.BrowserExecutableLocation Property**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxOptions_BrowserExecutableLocation.htm) it is defined as :

> Gets or sets the path and file name of the Firefox browser executable.

So the argument `options.BrowserExecutableLocation` must point to the *absolute path* of **firefox.exe** but not **geckodriver.exe**

### Solution

So if your usecase is to use the **firefox,exe** binary from a non-standard location you can use the following code block :

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\path\to\firefox.exe";
options.AddArgument("--headless");
c._driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

**Note** : You can find detailed discussions in :

- Selenium Issue [**error: Found argument '-f' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3410)
- GeckoDriver Issue [**error: Found argument '-f' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/474)

Comment: Your solution fixed it for me. I had to define the path to my firefox.exe. I also had to include the geckodriver in my project. Thanks a lot!